# variable number of parameters from a url/paramname/valueparam in an array?

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, parameters, action

basicly I would like to read url params in an array so finding params don't depend on their place in url

I have a url for seach with `controller/action/paramA/valueparamA/paramB/valueparamB`
theses params are optional : I have direct url with search params inside

to read params from url we have to use action(valueparamA, valueparamB)
but for me it seems really rigid
I want to read parameters by their name, not by their place in url!

so I can have different urls like

```
urlA = controller/action?paramA=valueA 
*(or controller/action/paramA/valueA)*
urlB controller/action?paramB=valueB
```

than I can use with the same action, like we do with a form with $_POST array (it and $_GET[} seems always empty when direct url params)
the best would be to have all parameters in an array[paramname=>paramvalue] like in a form

what I DON'T want is tu use differents actions for different parameters possibles! :)

the best I saw was to use juste on array like parameter :

```
controller/action/array[paramname=>paramvalue]
```

([passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter))
but it seems to complicate something basic : 
just read the normal url parameters like every framework knows :) with

```
url?nameparam=valueparam&...
```

hope there is a solution !
I begin tor eally like the light and quick of ci but sometimes (like for extending model) it seems a little "rigid" ;)

think in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep the URI class provides this functionality in the form of

```
$this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n);
```

This returns an array containing all parameters (keys and values must be defined in the URL).

Full details can be found on the Codigniter Userguide:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: big think mister!

with 
$this->uri->assoc_to_uri(arrayparams) 
to construct the url it works perfect! :)

when looking into forums I was afraid to have to "hack" with $get or expands model

you made my day ! ;)