# How to pass an array via $_GET in php?

Tags: php, arrays, get

How can I pass one or more variables of type array to another page via $_GET?

I always passed variable values in the form `?a=1&b=2&c=3`

What about passing `a=[1,2,3]` ?

Do I need to write a for loop and append all the values?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing arrays as url parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use the `[]` syntax to pass arrays through _GET:

```
?a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3
```

PHP understands this syntax, so `$_GET['a']` will be equal to `array(1, 2, 3)`.

You can also specify keys:

```
?a[42]=1&a[foo]=2&a[bar]=3
```

Multidimentional arrays work too:

```
?a[42][b][c]=1&a[foo]=2
```

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) does this automatically:

```
http_build_query(array('a' => array(1, 2, 3))) // "a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3"

http_build_query(array(
    'a' => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'bar' => array(1, 2, 3),
     )
)); // "a[foo]=bar&a[bar][]=1&a[bar][]=2&a[bar][]=3"
```

---

An alternative would be to pass json encoded arrays:

```
?a=[1,2,3]
```

And you can parse `a` with `json_decode`:

```
$a = json_decode($_GET['a']); // array(1, 2, 3)
```

And encode it again with json_encode:

```
json_encode(array(1, 2, 3)); // "[1,2,3]"
```

---

**Dont ever use `serialize()` for this purpose**. Serialize allows to serialize objects, and there is ways to make them execute code. So you should never deserialize untrusted strings.

Comment: +1 for json. just make sure you urlencode your json array to counter xss

Comment: `urlencode()` is not a way to counter xss. `htmlspecialchars()` is. But anyone should already `htmlspecialchars()` everything he outputs.

Comment: @arnoud: using urlencode inside attributes is safe. And when passing an url, you want it encoded for urls, not for markup (think `href=""`)

Comment: `urlencode()` is not meant to escape html, it's goal is to escape url components ;) So you just escape parameter names and values with urlencode(), and you escape the whole url with htmlspecialchars() before embeding it in a HTML document.

Comment: and the json_encoded array is what? it's an url component! urlencode encodes at least `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'` so you are on the safe side …

Comment: I didn't said to not use `urlencode()`; I said to not use it for html escaping purposes. Do not consider a url-encoded string as html-safe, they are not (e.g. it doesn't takes care of multibyte character sets). urlencode() is not a way to counter xss.

Comment: »Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits« shouldn't that take care of multibyte characters? they will simply be encoded as two entities. And I'm well aware that you should use `htmlspecialchars` for escaping HTML. My first comment probably wasn't very clear about that (should have read: to not produce invalid urls). Any way you should `urlencode` your array when appending it to an url, regardless of the discussion about XSS.

Comment: @arnaud576875 (knittl) -- you are both right since you are talking about 2 diff. things. You talk about output of GET passed data on actual page and you are dead-on; knittl is talking about encoding data passed via url - which should be done, but it does not prevent xss - it just prevents url from breaking; BTW: arnaud576875 - htmlspecialchars/htmlentities break http_build_query/json_encode treated data string, as &amp is prefixed (5.3 tested with no extra params)

Comment: The answer is not exactly true. In my case, if i put [] in my get request it would still recognise it as a single variable. I had to put the corresponding entities in the URL, which are %5B for [, and %5D for ].
    
Example: ?a%5B%5D=first&a%5B%5D=second

Comment: the first answer didn't work for me, but when I left the square brackets off it did. (Ex ?a=1&a=2&a=3)

Comment: @ArnaudLeBlanc Any way to parse Array type URL using `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass an associative array to [`http_build_query()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and append the resulting string as the query string to the URL. The array will automatically be parsed by PHP so `$_GET` on the receiving page will contain an array.

**Example**

```
$query_str = http_build_query(array(
    'a' => array(1, 2, 3)
));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$city_names = array(
    'delhi',
    'mumbai',
    'kolkata',
    'chennai'
);
$city_query = http_build_query(array('city' => $city_names));
```

this will give you:

```
city[0]=delhi&city[1]=mumbai&city[2]=kolkata&city[3]=chennai
```

if you want to encode the brackets also then use the below code:

```
$city_query = urlencode(http_build_query(array('city' => $city_names)));
```

Output:

```
city%255B0%255D%3Ddelhi%26city%255B1%255D%3Dmumbai .....
```

Reference: [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php), [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score -4):

Just repeat your `$_GET` variables like this: `name=john&name=lea`

This gives you an `array`.

I used to believe it would be overwritten!

Comment: This is incorrect. Repeating the parameter *will* overwrite. You must include the brackets on each `name` part in order to get an array. At least, that's what happens on PHP 5.3+.