# Is it possible to use PHP's [ ] array vars in a GET request?

Tags: php, arrays, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an array via $_GET in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206978/how-to-pass-an-array-via-get-in-php)

So I have a script which receives a $_POST with var Board[] containing an array of IDs.

I realized when adding ShareThis to the pages that folks wanting to share the result set would send an invalid link.

I definitely can add a delimited parameter to the script so ShareThis can pass

http://foo.com/bar.php?DelimitedBoard=3|4|5.

My question is whether there is a way to do this using the current Board[] var?

[http://foo.com/bar.php?Board[]=3,4,5](http://foo.com/bar.php)   fails.  Is there a way?

Comment: Answer found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206978/how-to-pass-an-array-via-get-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just do:

```
http://foo.com/bar.php?Board[]=3&Board[]=4&Board[]=5
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is something like this:

`http://foo.com/bar.php?Board[]=3&Board[]=4&Board[]=5`

Then, if you `print_r($_GET['Board']);` in `bar.php`, you will get something like:

```
Array (
  [0] => 3
  [1] => 4
  [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Number array serialization is very easy. Use `join(',', $Board)` to form a comma-separated ID string, use `explode(',', $_GET["Board"])` to get the array back.