# Pass URL-parameter as array in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I found in a [bundle](https://github.com/borNfreee/CommandRunnerBundle/blob/master/Controller/CommandRunnerController.php) those lines of code:

```
$params = $request->get('params');
if (!is_array($params)) {
    // Bad params
    $params = array();
}

$options = $request->get('options');
if (!is_array($options)) {
    // Bad options
    $options = array();
}
```

I wonder how to pass GET-parameters as an array?

```
http://url?params=...&options=...
```

Comment: `http://url?params[]=1&params[]=2&params[]=3...`

Comment: Everything you need can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207010/4583548)