# How to get object in query string using php

Tags: php

I have this url

http://localhost/url/stack.php?first=10&getthis=list&result=seats_booked[]=B2&seats_booked[]=B5&seats_booked[]=A20

```
$url = "first=10&getthis=list&result=seats_booked[]=B2&seats_booked[]=B5&seats_booked[]=A20";

parse_str($url);
echo  $seats_booked[0];
```

I want to get the values of array `seat_booked[]`.
I am trying this `echo  $seats_booked[0];` but it is returning an error.

How can achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code works fine, make sure you are not making any typos, enable error reporting.

Comment: simply you cannot pass an array like this in GET query, better use POST instead. If you insist to use GET anyway, check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206978/how-to-pass-an-array-via-get-in-php

Comment: @AlexAndrei it is not working, please note this are two different urls `first=10&getthis=list&result=seats_booked[]=B2&seats_booked[]=B5&seats_booked[]=A20` and this one `first=10&getthis=list&seats_booked[]=B2&seats_booked[]=B5&seats_booked[]=A20`

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `Undefined variable: seats_booked`