# PayPal error 520002: internal error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement adaptive payments but keep getting this weird error. Here's the request I'm sending:

```
POST https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay HTTP/1.1
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: kemal._1311606752_biz_api1.gmail.com
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: doesntmatter
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AeRGLhnzbfOKg7aJ9c5g0S5x4aMh
X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T
X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON
X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NVP
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 514

actionType=PAY&clientDetails.applicationId=test&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1&senderEmail=buyer_1320073183_per%40gmail.com&receiverList.receiver%280%29.email=seller_1320073277_biz%40gmail.com&receiverList.receiver%280%29.amount=588&cancelUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpay.dev%2Fcancel&currencyCode=EUR&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&ipnNotificationUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpay.dev%2Fipn&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpay.dev%2Freturn&requestEnvelope.detailLevel=ReturnAll&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError=true
```

Comment: A simple Google search shows that it could be a few different things, including the system is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself; PayPal API displays JAVA lists as query parameters but in reality you have to pass arrays of parameters to make it work.

Comment: Can you give more info how you solved this? I am having same problem.

Comment: @Sisir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't clientDetails.ipAddress be you public ip?

Comment: that's correct, though it changes nothing if I set it to my public IPv4