# Rails 3.1 find records filtered by array of IDs sent via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I have two tables:  projects and supplies.  Projects have many supplies, like this:

```
has_many :supplies, :through => :project_supplies, :foreign_key => :supply_id
```

One thing that I am trying to do is to select projects based on an array of supply id's.  I can do this in the rails console fairly easily with the following:

```
Project.find(:all, :joins => :supplies, :conditions => {:supplies => {:id => [17,18]}})
```

Being somewhat of a Rails noob, I can't seem to figure out how to go about sending that array as a parameter, and / or serializing it on the back-end.

I'm trying to do this  "GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects?supply_ids=[17,18]" in a way that rails understands.

Is that how I'm supposed to send the array?  If so, how do I get that into the conditions clause in array form?

I should also mention that I'm using Rails 3.1 and backbone.js.  The get request will come from the backbone fetch() function which accepts a "data" option just like $.ajax.  I already have the array built on the front-end.

To summarize, my question is this:  What exactly should go into the JavaScript data object attribute, and how do I wire that up to the controller model's find function as shown above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad format of array in URL string:
Use:

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects?supply_ids[]=17&supply_ids[]=18
```

Related topic:
[passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)