# Passing an array through url in php

Tags: php

I wish to pass an array through url. I checked at [passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter). Isnt there any other way? Below is my code

```
$result=Users.LoggedInUsers();
header('Location: http://localhost/Campus/Users.php?id='.$result.'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

[example](http://ideone.com/wsx3x)

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
echo http_build_query(array('arr'=>$arr));
//arr%5B0%5D=1&arr%5B1%5D=2&arr%5B2%5D=3&arr%5B3%5D=4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) it easily, then unserialize it to get it back to an array:

```
$result=serialize(Users.LoggedInUsers());
header('Location: http://localhost/Campus/Users.php?id='.$result.'');
```

Comment: If you unserialize untrusted input from a URL, be certain to validate the entire contents of the array.

Comment: It is showing following error
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

on Users.php i did

    $booksArr = $_GET['id'];
    $result=unserialize(urldecode($booksArr));