# http_build_query and URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, php, input

I have a from with inputs with array name like `foo[]` so when submitting the form my url become `foo[]=lorem&foo[]=ipsum` but when using php `http_build_query` to regenerate this sort of query it adds key to the array like this `foo[0]=lorem&foo[1]=ipsum`.

My issue is that on the front I'm using `URLSearchParams.getAll('foo[]')` to get the value, but it works only without the array keys added by `http_build_query`.

So is there a way to use `URLSearchParams` with this format ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996573/php-url-query-nested-array-with-no-index you can additionally format the output by using regex to match and remove the indexes of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Plamen Nikolov link I fixed my issue by changing my Javascript to handle the inputs that are arrays with or without index keys (added by PHP with http_build_query) like this :

```
// Before
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// After
let urlQuery = decodeURI(window.location.search).replace(/\[\d+\]/g, "[]");
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(urlQuery);
```