# Symfony HttpClient GET request with multiple query string parameters with same name

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-http-client

I am trying to make an API request in the following format:

```
/api/v1/courses?enrollment_state=active&include[]=total_students&include[]=term
```

How can I do so using the `HttpClient` Component query string parameters?

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/v1/courses', [
      'query' => [
           'enrollment_state' => 'active',
           'include[]' => 'term',
           'include[]' => 'total_students',
       ],
]);
```

As the above approach does not work due to duplicate array key?

I have also tried:

```
'include[]' => ['term', 'total_students']
```

Comment: Did you try using only one 'include' key and passing 'term' and 'total_students' inside an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create the equivalent to:

```
https://www.example.com/?token=foo&abc[]=one&abc[]=two
```

Just do:

```
$client->request(
    'GET',
    'https://www.example.com/',
    [
        'query' => [
            'token' => 'foo',
            'abc' => ['one', 'two']
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: An issue with this approach is that the resulting query string is actually in format: https://www.example.com/?token=foo&abc[0]=one&abc[1]=two. Do you know how it would be possible to build this query without number indices?

Answer (score 0):

as @user1392897 says, @yivi snippet returns indexes in the url query string.

```
https://www.example.com/?foo[0]=bar&foo[1]=baz
```

That's because it use the `http_build_query` built in function and it's the function behaviour. You can read this thread [php url query nested array with no index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996573/php-url-query-nested-array-with-no-index) about it.

A workaround it to **build the query string yourself** from the array and append it to your url, the the 2nd parameter of the `HttpClient->request()` method.

```php
function createQueryString(array $queryArray = []): ?string
{
    $queryString = http_build_query($queryArray, '', '&', \PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
    $queryString = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '%5B%5D=', $queryString); //foo[]=x&foo[]=y
    
    return '' !== $queryString ? $queryString : null;
}

$queryArray = [
    'abc' => ['one', 'two']
];

$queryString = createQueryString($queryArray);

$url = 'https://www.example.com/';
if (is_string($queryString)) {
    $url = sprintf('%s?%s', $url, $queryString);
}

$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
```