# Pass array with keys via HTTP GET

Tags: php, http, get, http-get

I have tried to pass array data to the PHP script with request:

```
script.php?page=7&filter[key]=value
```

but didn't receive it in the script. Can I do so and if no - how can I pass array with HTTP GET?

Comment: Can you post the code to generate the request?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass a whole array or just one value?

Comment: Can you try: `filter[]=value1&filter[]=value2` and see what you get on PHP side.. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko i tried and i am getting the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely pass array from url  and to get the value on php page,

```
$testvar = $_GET['filter'];
echo $testvar['key'];
```

and just out of curiosity i tried to `$_GET['filter']['value']` and it too worked !!!

and if you want to pass multiple array vals, you can use **[http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will get those value in an array on `script.php` page

Just try to print the array value in the `script.php` page.

`print_r($_GET['filter']);`

Answer (score 0):

you have to just pass the data like this

```
script.php?page=7&filter=value
```

and use `is_array()` for checking that incoming data is array or not like this

```
is_array($_GET['filter'])
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: And how you propose describe `value` in URL if it's an array?

Comment: just pass the array value in it. like this `&filter=<php $array_value; ?>`

Comment: and how it will look in the URL? :) In browser for example.