# PHP: How to check total no. parameters in URL?

Tags: php, mysql, query-string

i am retrieving the parameters using $_REQUEST. Is there a way of finding total no. of parameters in URL instead of retrieving each one and then counting ?

Comment: what abount count($_GET) count($_POST) or count($_REQUEST) isnt working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you the total number of `&` separated URL query parameters:

```
count(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
```

If you only want unique parameters, use `$_GET` instead:

```
count($_GET)
```

Comment: thanks. on the basis of your idea i used count($_REQUEST) that worked too.

Comment: @New_2_PHP [`$_REQUEST` does not just contain URL parameters but also POST parameters and cookies.](http://php.net/reserved.variables.request)

Answer (score 4):

Retrieve them with `$_GET`. This should be enough.

Example:

```
// url: index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3
echo count($_GET); // 3 params, $_GET['a'], $_GET['b'], $_GET['c']
```

Note: you can also pass arrays in url ( [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter) ), and the whole array is counted once.

Comment: Good catch on arrays. Deleting mine in your favor

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you. Try this :

```
$total = count($_GET);
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the parameters in the URL, it's better to use $_GET.
Since $_REQEUST contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. [see php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

And if you want to know the number of parameters, you can get count the number of parameters that are in the URL using this: `count($_GET)`.