# HTML URL query encoding for String array?

Tags: html, url, encoding

So I have two parameters I want to pass, one is a string and the other is an array named query and tags. 
The problem is that tags has multiple values (like an array). I tried

```
/?query=val&tags=val1+val2+val3
```

But since my val1,2,3 may have spaces in them, the encoding messes it up because space is encoded as '+'. Also can't use multiple variables since the length of the array is dynamic.
How should I encode this?

EDIT: for the answers on the similar question, the array is split by &'s, however that is reserved for splitting the query into parameters. Is there a way of encoding this such that the parameter stays between two &'s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass an array within a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: Did you try using &nbsp; ?

Also check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up encoding with a semi-colon to separate the values instead.
In my servlet I then parsed the string to an array accordingly