# How to use array values in another php file?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, query-string

I'm using PHP, Smarty, MySQL for my website. I have an array of error messages and I want to use this array in a PHP file to which I'm redirecting the control. However, I'm not understanding how should I achieve this.

code is as follows:

```
$error_msg  = $contact_us->GetAllErrors();
$smarty->assign('error_msg', $error_msg);
$return_url = "view_contact_us.php?page=".$_SESSION['contact_us']."&from_date={$from_date}&to_date={$to_date}&contact_full_name={$contact_full_name}&contact_label={$hidden_contact_label}&error_msg=".$error_msg;
header("Location:".$return_url);
```

I tried many different ways, but I'm not able to use the array `$error_msg` in the file `view_contact_us.php`.

If I print the array $error_msg it looks like following:

```
   Array
(
    [error_msgs] => Please select at least one enquiry
Please select at least one enquiry label
)
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION` variable and put or assign your `array()` as its value.

For example:

```
$arr = array();

$arr[0] = "error_1";
$arr[1] = "error_2";
$arr[2] = "error_3";

$_SESSION['errorMsg'] = $arr;
```

After that, `$_SESSION['errorMsg']` can now be use globally throughout all webpages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you suggest me another way which would not make use of session variables?

Comment: In that case, please see Awlad Liton's comment on your question, i think it relates more to your issue.