# How do I pass variables as url parameters in cURL array to CURLOPT_URL

Tags: php, arrays, variables, curl, url-parameters

I have this php code using cURL to parse an xml feed from Indeed.com. I'm passing server information such as REMOTE_ADDR and HTTP_USER_AGENT into the parameters of the url but they are not being passed.

Check this part of the code below. `'.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'`

This is the correct way to do it. Just not sure if it is the correct way to do it when it is part of an array in CURLOPT_URL =>

What is the proper way to pass these server snippets into the url parameters when using an array in cURL like in the below function in CURLOPT_URL =>?

The below php code is the entire code on my page so you can get a better idea of what is going on.

I'm trying to detect the users city, state when they arrive at my site to display job listings in their local area. The php code works and I can echo the city state on the web page, but it is just not passing that same info to the function curl_request() in the array. Please help.

```
<?php
// Convert IP into city state country (Geo Location function)
function geoCheckIP($ip){
if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
throw new InvalidArgumentException("IP is not valid");
}

$response=@file_get_contents('http://www.netip.de/search?query='.$ip);
if (empty($response))
{
throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error contacting Geo-IP-Server");
}

$patterns=array();
$patterns["domain"] = '#Domain: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';
$patterns["country"] = '#Country: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';
$patterns["state"] = '#State/Region: (.*?)<br#i';
$patterns["town"] = '#City: (.*?)<br#i';

$ipInfo=array();

foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern)
{

$ipInfo[$key] = preg_match($pattern,$response,$value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1] : 'not found';
}
/*I've included the substr function for Country to exclude the abbreviation (UK, US, etc..)
To use the country abbreviation, simply modify the substr statement to:
substr($ipInfo["country"], 0, 3)
*/
$ipdata = $ipInfo["town"]. ", ".$ipInfo["state"]/*.", ".substr($ipInfo["country"], 4)*/;
return $ipdata;
}


// Indeed php function
function curl_request(){
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=&q=computer+repair&l='.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&sort=&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&highlight=1&filter=1&latlong=0&co=us&chnl=computer+help+wanted&userip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&useragent='.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'&v=2',
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $resp;
}

function xmlToArray($input, $callback = null, $recurse = false) {
$data = ((!$recurse) && is_string($input))? simplexml_load_string($input, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA): $input;
if ($data instanceof SimpleXMLElement) $data = (array) $data;
if (is_array($data)) foreach ($data as &$item) $item = xmlToArray($item, $callback, true);
return (!is_array($data) && is_callable($callback))? call_user_func($callback, $data): $data;
}
?>
```

**FUNCTION CALL**

This is how the function is called in the body

```
    <ol>
  <?php

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){    // using for loop to show number of  jobs

$resp=curl_request($i);

$arrXml = xmlToArray($resp);

$results=$arrXml['results'];

?>
  <li>
    <p><strong>Job :</strong> <a href="<?php echo $results['result'][$i]['url']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $results['result'][$i]['jobtitle']; ?></a></p>
    <p><strong>Company:</strong> <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['company']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['formattedLocationFull']; ?></p>
    <p><strong>Date Posted :</strong> <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['formattedRelativeTime'];?> on <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['date'];?></p>
    <p><strong>Description :</strong> <?php echo $results['result'][$i]['snippet']; ?></p>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

**What works**

This code above works only if I remove the variables from the CURLOPT_URL

**This works**

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=&q=computer+repair&l=city,state&sort=&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&highlight=1&filter=1&latlong=0&co=us&chnl=computer+help+wanted&userip=111.111.111.111&useragent=mozila&v=2',
```

**This does not work**

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=&q=computer+repair&l='.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&sort=&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&highlight=1&filter=1&latlong=0&co=us&chnl=computer+help+wanted&userip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&useragent='.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'&v=2',
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the `geoCheckIP()` part of the URL to static text??

Comment: @Novocaine88 Yes. it works when I change this part `'.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'` to static text like this `new york, ny` or a static zip code works too `10001`. Can you still help with this?

Comment: My only suggestion is that possibly your `geoCheckIP` function is not working properly. If you use it on it's own, does it return a string as expected? I suspect it doesn't, considering switching that function with static text works.

Comment: @Novocaine88 yes the geocheckip works fine. I am not using this code after all. There is a way better code without curl I am using now. Something was wrong with the curl code and it was super slow in loading too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cURL is not needed for this and was loading very slow. Here is a very simple way to get the results of the xml document in pure php with the geoCheckIP function fully working with it.

```
<?php

// Convert IP into city state country (Geo Location function)
function geoCheckIP($ip){
    if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('IP is not valid');
    }

    $response=@file_get_contents('http://www.netip.de/search?query='.$ip);
    if (empty($response))
    {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Error contacting Geo-IP-Server');
    }

    $patterns=array();
    $patterns["domain"] = '#Domain: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';
    $patterns["country"] = '#Country: (.*?)&nbsp;#i';
    $patterns["state"] = '#State/Region: (.*?)<br#i';
    $patterns["town"] = '#City: (.*?)<br#i';

    $ipInfo=array();

    foreach ($patterns as $key => $pattern)
    {

    $ipInfo[$key] = preg_match($pattern,$response,$value) && !empty($value[1]) ? $value[1] : 'not found';
    }
    /*I've included the substr function for Country to exclude the abbreviation (UK, US, etc..)
    To use the country abbreviation, simply modify the substr statement to:
    substr($ipInfo["country"], 0, 3)
    */
    $ipdata = $ipInfo["town"]. ", ".$ipInfo["state"]/*.", ".substr($ipInfo["country"], 4)*/;
    return $ipdata;
}


// Indeed.com API URL parameters
$url = 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch'.'?';
$publisher = 'YOUR PUB NUMBER GOES HERE';
$q = 'title:(java or java+programmer or java+programming)';
$l = geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$sort = 'date';
$radius = '20';
$st = '';
$jt = '';
$start = '0';
$limit = '25';
$fromage = '';
$highlight = '0';
$filter = '1';
$latlong = '0';
$co = 'us';
$chnl = 'YOUR CHANNEL NAME';
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$useragent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) : 'unknown';
$v = '2';
```

Then the rest of the code you see below will go below the `<body>` tag of your page where you want the output to show up at.

```
    <!-- BEGIN INDEED ORDERED LIST-->
    <ol class="jobs">
      <?php

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url."publisher=".$publisher."&q=".$q."&l=".$l."&sort=".$sort."&radius=".$radius."&st=".$st."&jt=".$jt."&start=".$start."&limit=".$limit."&fromage=".$fromage."&highlight=".$highlight."&filter=".$filter."&latlong=".$latlong."&co=".$co."&chnl=".$chnl."&userip=".$userip."&useragent=".$useragent."&v=".$v);

    foreach($xml->results->result as $result) { ?>
      <li class="job">
        <div id="jobtitle"><strong><a onmousedown="<?php echo $result->onmousedown;?>" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $result->url;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $result->jobtitle;?></a></strong></div>
        <div id="company"><?php echo $result->company;?></div>
        <div id="snippet">
          <?php echo $result->snippet;?>
        </div>
        <div id="location"><strong>Location:</strong> <?php echo $result->formattedLocationFull;?></div>
        <div id="date"><span class="posted">Posted <?php echo $result->formattedRelativeTime;?></span></div>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <!-- END INDEED ORDERED LIST -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a proper explanation here:
[passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

You can just take the syntax from there and use it with curl!

example for a function which should help you create a url-param in array-form:

```
public function createArrParam($key, $values) {
    return implode('&amp;' . $key . '[]=', array_map('urlencode', $values));
}
```

after that you just take your url and concatenate it with the result:

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com?bla=blupp' . createArrParam('myArr', $values);
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not answer

Comment: i'll make it an answer then... ;)! thanks @hindmost i'll extend it!

Comment: @PLM57 be so kind to put the code together from the php in my above code. I'm interested to see how this will work.

Answer (score -1):

Like so;

```
function curl_request()
{
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options
    $curl_config = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "publisher" => "",
            "q" => "computer+repair",
            "l" => $user_location,
            "sort" => "",
            "radius" => 25,
            "st" => "",
            "jt" => "",
            "start" => "",
            "limit" => "",
            "fromage" => "",
            "highlight" => 1,
            "filter" => 1,
            "latlong" => 0,
            "co" => "us",
            "chnl" => "computer+help+wanted",
            "userip" => $user_ip,
            "useragent" => $user_agent,
            "v" => 2
        )
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_config);
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);
    return $resp;
}
```

**EDIT**
There may be 1, possibly 2 reasons why this isn't working for you;

**1.** your not passing in the variables you've defined outside the function (neither did I in my first answer).
To fix this you either need to pass them in like so `function curl_request($user_ip, $user_agent, $user_location)` in your function definition and as well when calling the function. Or change how you enter them in the URL string;

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=&q=computer+repair&l='.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']).'&sort=&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&highlight=1&filter=1&latlong=0&co=us&chnl=computer+help+wanted&userip='.$$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&useragent='.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'&v=2'
));
```

`$_SERVER` is a global variable so it does not need passing into the function as a parameter to work like this.

**2.** The api your calling does not accept `POST` requests only `GET` in which case my first example wont work, and your first example should work, once you pass through the variables as outlined in point **1.**

Comment: the variables I'm trying to pass in the url parameters are $user_ip and $user_agent and $user_location. I don't get where to put that in this code.

Comment: see my edit, ive added some of the variables, hopefully that should show you how to add the rest. The parameter name is on the left of the array, and the value of that parameter is on the right.

Comment: updated to add all parameters, and changed the url as in your example

Comment: doesn't seem to work. How would I echo the results to test it?

Comment: apologies, I accidentally removed the `curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_config);` line. Back now, try again.

Comment: still does not work. I used this `curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
 CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=3536469995720671&q=computer+repair&l='.geoCheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&sort=&radius=25&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&highlight=1&filter=1&latlong=0&co=us&chnl=computer+help+wanted&userip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'&useragent='.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'&v=2',
 ));`

Comment: updated my code above in the original question so you can take a look at everything in my page.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $url = 'https://localhost/host/wp-json/wc/v3';
 $consumer_key = 'ck_63dbe94df1343';
 $consumer_secret = 'cs_120aa6787d';
 $collection_name = 'customers';
 $request_url = $url . '/' . $collection_name . '?consumer_Key=' . $consumer_key . '&consumer_secret=' . $consumer_secret;

 $curl = curl_init($request_url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```