# Include Call to Action in Facebook Video Upload to Page - Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, file-upload

I have the following working code for video upload to a Facebook page Timeline:

```
$file = $my_video;
$video_title = $my_title;
$video_desc = $my_description;
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/".$fb_page_id."/videos?"
         . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
         . "&access_token=". $access_token;

$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'file', 'file' => '@'.realpath($file));// use realpath
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
$video_id = $res['id'];
```

I would like to add a call to action to the request, which is documented [here from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/page-posts-with-cta).

I tried the following:

```
$fb_action = strtoupper($the_action);
$fb_action_link = $action_link;
$call_to_action = "&call_to_action={'type':'".$fb_action."','value':{'link':'".$fb_action_link."'}}";

$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/".$fb_page_id."/videos?"
         . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc . $call_to_action
         . "&access_token=". $access_token;
```

And I also tried:

```
$call_to_action = "&call_to_action=['type','".$fb_action."','value',['link','".$fb_action_link."']]";
```

I keep getting an error back immediately from Facebook. Does anyone know if this is a formatting issue? Any suggestions for the proper way? Hugely appreciated !

Comment: I also tried putting the associated array into the $data param - 'call_to_action' => array('type' => $fb_action, 'value' => array('link' => $fb_action_link)); Still an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was really the formatting of the arrays. I found out that http_build_query() was the solution which is apparently how Facebook developers encode their params. This post helped me a lot - >
[passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

The final solution is here:

```
$action_call_array = array('type' => $fb_action, 'value' => array('link' => $fb_action_link));
$params = http_build_query(array('call_to_action' => $action_call_array));

$post_url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/'.$fb_page_id.'/videos?'
         . 'title=' . $video_title. '&description=' . $video_desc . '&' . urldecode($params) 
         . '&access_token='. $m_page_access_token;
```

Plug $post_url into curl then and works great! Hope this helps someone, took me a while to find and test the right answer, and looks like this solution would work for other Facebook endpoints with arrays in the params.

Comment: I am using your code, and it seems to upload correctly (no errors), but somehow facebook ignores my input. All other data (title, description etc) is stored fine, but call_to_action is fully ignored. Any idea?

Comment: I've been having issues with facebook video upload recently too. I'll update this answer once I've revisited the issue!