# Get VALUES from url in PHP

Tags: php, get

I need to get ID´s from url:

```
http://www.aaaaa/galery.php?position=kosice&kategory=Castles&ID=1&ID=5&ID=24&ID=32
```

If i use `$_GET['ID']` a still get only last ID value. I need to get all of them to array, or select.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan He has 3 different IDs, getting it simply with the $_GET is not going to solve the problem he has.

Comment: @Jordy then use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] :)

Comment: doesnt look like a valid request string to me, `ID[]=1&ID[]=5`  would make sense

Comment: use different name for vars or use a form method post with array =)

Answer (score 6):

Use array syntax:

```
 http://www.aaaaa/galery.php?position=kosice&kategory=Castles&ID[]=1&ID[]=5&ID[]=24&ID[]=32

var_dump($_GET['ID']);

array(4) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(5)
      [2]=>
      int(24)
      [3]=>
      int(32)
      }
} 

echo $_GET['ID'][2]; // 24
```

Comment: What if he does not want to use [] (array) in his query string? You should write that solution either.

Answer (score 5):

The format in the URL is wrong. The second "ID" is overwriting the first "ID".. use an array:

```
http://www.example.org/?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

In PHP:

```
echo $_GET['id'][0]; // 1
echo $_GET['id'][1]; // 2
echo $_GET['id'][2]; // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this you need to make ID as array and pass it in the URL

http://www.aaaaa/galery.php?position=kosice&kategory=Castles&ID[]=1&ID[]=5&ID[]=24&ID[]=32
and this can be manipulated at the backend like this

```
$urls = $_GET['ID'];
foreach($urls as $url){
   echo $url;
}
```

**OR**

An alternative would be to pass json encoded arrays

http://www.aaaaa/galery.php?position=kosice&kategory=Castles&ID=[1,2,24,32]

which can be used as

```
$myarr = json_decode($_GET['ID']); // array(1,2,24,32)
```

I recommend you to also see for this here.
[http_build_query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

it's wrong but if you really want to do this

```
<?php

function getIds($string){
    $string = preg_match_all("/[ID]+[=]+[0-9]/i", $string, $matches);

    $ids = [];

    foreach($matches[0] as $match)
    {
       $c = explode("=", $match);
       $ids [] = $c[1];         
    }

    return $ids;
}


// you can change this with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
$url = "http://www.aaaaa/galery.php?position=kosice&kategory=Castles&ID=1&ID=5&ID=24&ID=32";

$ids = getIds($url);


var_dump($ids);
```