# Pass array from URL to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How can i pass an array from a GET request like this:

```
[x, y], [x, y]...
```

Into the second part of this google visualization API call.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Initial', 'Second'],
[8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);
```

Currently i have the values pre-set, but i would like to pass them from a GET request.
I have tried using PHP for this however failed using methods like this [passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter) as i am not quite sure how to set the x value properly.

Below is the script i use to generate the chart:

```
  <script>
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Initial', 'Second'],
        [8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]]);

      var options = {
        width: 420,
        height: 420,
        legend: 'none',
        trendlines: { 0: {} },
        colors: ['#FE2E2E'],
        hAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: "#CCCCCC"
            },
            baselineColor: '#CCCCCC'
        },
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: "#CCCCCC"
            },
            baselineColor: '#CCCCCC'
        },
        enableInteractivity: false
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: The code which you have pasted is not a GET API call. I guess you want to parse the response from a GET call and set the data into the code. Am I correct?

Comment: If you will specify what chart you will use the data into. I can give you a working example.

Comment: Well looks like answer below was accepted and I don't have a scatter chart. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the response from the GET request:-

```
 var myArrayData = JSON.parse(responseData);
```

Now your data will be of the form

```
[8, 37], [4, 19.5], [11, 52], [4, 22], [3, 16.5], [6.5, 32.8], [14, 72]
```

Then do:

```
myArrayData.unshift(['Initial', 'Second']);
```

Now you can try:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myArrayData);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could stringify it and pass as url encoded

```
var a = [[4,5], [6,7]];
var b = JSON.stringify(a); // "[[4,5], [6,7]]"
var x = encodeURIComponent(b); // "%5B%5B4%2C5%5D%2C%20%5B6%2C7%5D%5D"
var strArray = decodeURIComponent(x); // "[[4,5], [6,7]]"
var myArray = JSON.parse("[[4,5], [6,7]]"); // [[4,5], [6,7]]
```