# How send multiple values through query string to another page in php?

Tags: php, function

I have multiple values so i want to send them in query string. I have found a solution from stackoverflow but it does not working properly. Can any on guide me where i'm wrong.

### URL

```
www.xyz.com/action=exe?check_ids[]=38&check_ids[]=36&check_ids[]=35
```

### Getting Values from Url

```
echo $_REQUEST['check_ids'];
```

Comment: `action=exe?check_id...` isn't going to work, it should be `?action=exe&check_id....`.

Comment: Refer this One. Already Solved 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For url like www.xyz.com/action?check_ids[]=38&check_ids[]=36&check_ids[]=35 you can do this :

```
echo $_REQUEST['check_ids'][0]; //print 38
echo $_REQUEST['check_ids'][1]; //print 36
```

OR use this

```
foreach($_REQUEST['check_ids'] as $id)
        echo $id;//this will print the individual values
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do it by using commas:

> http://www.example.com/?action=exe&check_ids=38,36,35

```
// to get an array use explode
var_dump(explode(",", $_GET['check_ids']);
```