# How to send object data in URL?

Tags: php, object, url, post, get

I have one client URL . They are requested me to send all the data to in one object to insert their database .

How can I send so many field data in one object ?

**Example URL:**

`http://example.com/Order/Insert/{MerchantId}/{Secretkey}/{Relationcode}{object data}`

I have {MerchantId}, {Secretkey}, {Relationcode} and {object data }.

> Object data  contains following fields:
>
> OrderNo, LoginId, shipCharge, CompanyDiscount, totalMRP, totalquantity etc.

How can I send all these data as object data ?

Please suggest me some good way.

Comment: Please don't forget to search on Google / Stack before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Comment: maybe you can use base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I would send the JSON in the URL but encode it to make it look more professional, possibly with base64_encode()

Comment: is it a good practice to send encoded JSON in the URL as RouterParams ?