# Passsing Arrays in URL Minimum value of a list without using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to pass arryas in url using PHP

Comment: just one word: http_build_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it as a series of GETs and then form an array after this?

e.g.

```
<?php
// URL = http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Ahmadabad&CountryName=India
$array = [];
foreach($_GET as $get)
{
    $array[] = $get;
}
var_dump($array);
?>
```

Not sure if this is what you are after but it seems to be the only option that I can see (I'd love someone else to be able to do this fully using an array in the URI!)

Or, you could use a header relocation:

```
header("Location: http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Ahmadabad&CountryName=India");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It will not work this way. Better solution would be to save values in session variable and fetch them on next page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $params = http_build_query($array1);
```

Output will be: `CityName=Ahmadabad&CountryName=India`

```
$client = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?' . $params;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using this simpler way:
**http_build_query**

Example:
i got this from here: [passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter/1764199#1764199)

```
$data = array(
    1,
    4,
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd'
);
$query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $data));
```

that's it.. :)