# URL building with array parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a URL using jQuery `serialize()` and it creates something like this:

> client_number=4&start_date&client_number=5

the problem is that I would like to have an url with arrays like this:

> client_number[]=4&start_date&client_number[]=5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1764199/989920

Comment: What's the difference? A url is just a meaningless string. If you want it to be handled as an array, then handle it as an array in whatever code accesses the url.

Comment: @4castle - I commented too soon.

Comment: @4castle, PHP uses this particular non-standard array syntax to automatically parse query strings on the server and populate `$_GET`. Without the `[]` characters, the behavior is drastically different.

Comment: @zzzzBov Who said anything about PHP? The OP needs to explain why they are doing this. If it's in order to use the convenience methods in PHP, then I understand.

Comment: @4castle, I brought up PHP because that's the only place I've seen the `[]` syntax used, and this question exactly matches the use case.

Comment: @4castle it's inappropriate and rude to make sweeping changes to a question without feedback from the OP. while I'm certain that the use case is for PHP, I'm not about to go changing the tags or question until stefano responds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an array within a query string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: If you were going to fix this question so that it isn't a duplicate, then you need to ask a question such as "I see the answers to this other question, but what solutions are there that use jQuery?" Then it would be an acceptable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[name]` of the input elements that are being serialized must contain `[]` to produce those PHP compatible query strings.

```js
$(function () {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $('pre').text($(this).serialize());
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="example1">
  <input type="text" name="example1">
  <input type="text" name="example2[]">
  <input type="text" name="example2[]">
  <input type="submit" value="Serialize">
</form>
<pre></pre>
```

---

**Note:** the keys will appear with `%5B%5D` instead of `[]`. This is expected and OK because that is the proper URL encoding for `[]`.

Comment: This is an HTML answer to a JavaScript question. OP never tagged HTML, which makes an HTML answer inappropriate. Sound familiar?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was selected. It's a workaround among actual answers. I feel like if anyone was Googling around and found this page, this answer wouldn't help them a bit. If this is the correct answer to the question, then the question is actually a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string).

Comment: @4castle, it's not a workaround when it's the expected solution for serializing a form to PHP. The difference between this question and the question you've linked is that this question is with regard to getting jQuery's serialize to work with PHP's query string array syntax while the other one is about how to just post to PHP directly. If jQuery had a different behavior, the answer to this question would need to change while the answer to the other wouldn't.

Comment: But the question never mentioned a form. This question actually **did** ask just how to post the data. If you aren't going to use jQuery or modify the behavior of jQuery `serialize`, then how is this an answer to the question? The question that I linked has this as an answer.

Comment: The behavior of jQuery `serialize` is identical to how a browser serializes a form, so jQuery really isn't doing anything unique to merit a separate question.

Comment: @4castle, The question mentioned using [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which works with `<form>` elements.

Comment: Right, but I'm saying if this is the answer to the question, then jQuery is not relevant, and this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @4castle, I understood what you were saying the first time. I also disagree with it. Comments are not the place for this sort of extended discussion. If enough others agree with you this question will be closed anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108645/discussion-between-4castle-and-zzzzbov).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to append `[]` to the duplicate query string items.

A JavaScript solution would be to use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) on the form, mark the key/value pairs which are duplicates, add `[]` to the the name properties of the duplicates, and then convert the object back to a query string using [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).

```
function serializeWithDuplicates(form) {
    var pairs = $(form).serializeArray();
    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < pairs.length; j++)
            if (pairs[i].name === pairs[j].name)
                pairs[i].isDuplicate = pairs[j].isDuplicate = true;
    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
        if (pairs[i].isDuplicate)
            pairs[i].name += "[]";
    return $.param(pairs);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tupgn7mo/4/)

Comment: I've updated my code so it's much better. See what you think!