# How can i get the value through URL from the product page arrays

Tags: php

I have two pages how can i get the value from the product page through url if i click on the product name it redirect to specification page and get the value from the producat page array.

**PHP**

**product page**

```
$array1 = Array(["b"]=>"value['brand']",
            ["ref"]=>"value2['reference']

<a href="product.php?post=reference&<?php echo urlencode(serialize($array1));?>">

<h3 id="custompage">Product Name</span></h3></a>
```

**Specification PAGE**

```
<h3 id="custom"><?php echo $_GET['brand']; ?><span><br></span></h3>
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing arrays as url parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for `http_build_query().`

```
<?php

$array1 = Array(
    "b"=>"brand",
    "ref"=>"reference");

echo http_build_query($array1);
//b=brand&ref=reference

echo http_build_query($array1, '', '&amp;');
//b=brand&ref=reference

?>
```