# Passing array using header

Tags: php, arrays, header

I am having trouble with following code

```
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($value);
header("location:home.php?result=$res");
```

This is not working! The url seems to be `home.php?result=Array`. How can I pass the array `$res` without using session?

Comment: We can't pass array to url directly. You have to pass value.
Show us your code that we can help.

Comment: Please refer this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Comment: Why you need to pass whole array? Do a SQL query on the target page.

Answer (score 2):

You should first generate URL-encoded query string using [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($value);
$res = http_build_query($res);
header("location:home.php?result=$res");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefer [**http_build_query**()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function to encode in string and then send to querystring

```
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($value);
header("location:home.php?result=".http_build_query($res));
```

Have a look an example for that

```
 <?php

    $data = array('email' => 'test@test.com',
        array("php", "mysql"),
        'age' => 28);
    echo 'page2.php?' . http_build_query($data);
    //output: page2.php?email=test%40test.com&0%5B0%5D=php&0%5B1%5D=mysql&age=28
    ?>
```

Comment: This Solution was already posted by @T.AKROUT.