# http_build_query giving me get parameters of the same name

Tags: php

I'm sending multiple parameters to another page, and I am using `http_build_query()` to do this. The following code:

```
$array = array();

if(!empty($_POST['modelcheck'])){
    foreach($_POST['modelcheck'] as $selected){
        $array[] = $selected;
    }
}

$args = array
(
    'pricefrom' => $fromval,
    'priceto' => $toval,
    'model' => $array
);
    $params = http_build_query($args);
    $cleanedParams = preg_replace('/%5B(\d+?)%5D/', '', $params);


header("Location: ../page2.php?" . $cleanedParams);
```

gives me a url:

```
page2.php?pricefrom=10000&priceto=60000&model=1&model=2
```

As you can see model is repeated multiple times, I would like the parameters following the first `model` to be `model2`, `model3`.......etc.

I've tried putting it in a for loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($array) ; $i++) { 
    $args = array
    (
        'pricefrom' => $fromval,
        'priceto' => $toval,
        'model'.$i => $array
    );
}
```

but this just gives me :

```
page2.php?pricefrom=10000&priceto=60000&model1=1&model1=2
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want it to be `&model1=1&model1=2` and not `&model[]=1&model[]=2`?

Comment: @Dharman What I want is `&model1=1&model2=2`,

Comment: You should use `&model[]=1&model[]=2` which will be an array on the other end and also you won't need to try and clean up with preg_replace.

Comment: if models are always integers, why not send all in one as `&model=1,2,3` and later use `$models = explode(",",$_GET['model']);` this will turn "1,2,3" into an array where $models[0] => "1", $models[1] => "2" and so on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your `$args` variable should look like:

```php
$args = array (
    'pricefrom' => $fromval,
    'priceto' => $toval,
    'model' => $array
);
```

**UPD**

Use `preg_replace` for replace html special chars if you want to use `http_build_query` with multiple params.

```php
$query = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '[]=', http_build_query($args));
```

You will receive an array by accessing to `$_GET['model']`

Comment: This is giving me: `page2.php?pricefrom=10000&priceto=60000&model%5B%5D=70cc&model%5B%5D=125cc`

Comment: `html_build_query` does not exists in PHP. What is exactly the purpose of `preg_replace` in your example?

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting `model[]=1&model[]=2` , shouldn't it be `model1=1&model2=2`?

Comment: Nevermind used ` $_GET['model'][0];` to get the required result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second parameter in [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to prefix the numerical keys with a string:

```
$args = array
(
    'pricefrom' => $fromval,
    'priceto' => $toval
);
$args += $array; // merge the two arrays together
$params = http_build_query($args, 'model', '&amp;'); // use a second arg for prefix.
```

However, I do not recommend to create separate names for variables like this. Better to use `&model[]=1&model[]=2`. See [Passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1764199/1839439)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I might use the `&model[]=1&model[]=2` approach as suggested below as well.

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with your original code except that you broke it with the call to `preg_replace`.

```
if(!empty($_POST['modelcheck'])){
    foreach($_POST['modelcheck'] as $selected){
        $models[] = $selected;
    }
}

$args = [
    'pricefrom' => $fromval,
    'priceto' => $toval,
    'model' => $models,
];

$params = http_build_query($args);
header("Location: ../page2.php?" . $params);
```

Now, in `page2.php` you just use `$_GET['model']` as an array.

```
<?php
foreach ($_GET['model'] as $model) {
    printf('%s<br/>', $model);
}
```