# Laravel - multiple parameters in the URL

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a simple foreach loop that loops through the current week dates in `Y-m-d` format:

```php
@foreach($dates as $date)
   <a href="{{route('consols.index', array_merge(\Request::query(), ['date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))]))}}">{{date('l', strtotime($date))}}</a>
@endforeach
```

With above, I can simply click on the anchor link, and the specific date will be appended:

```php
example.org/consols?date=2020-03-04
```

Now I use this to filter a specific SQL query and I wish to be able to filter for multiple dates. For example:

```php
example.org/consols?date=2020-03-04&date=2020-03-05&date=2020-03-06
```

Where in above example, I wish to send 3 dates as query parameters.

If I simply append another `&date=` to the already present `?date`, it will only select the last `date=` in the query string.

How can I, with PHP, send multiple variables in my URL with the same parameter name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arrays as url parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking at the link CodyKL [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter), and from there saw that I could actually use `http_build_query`.

This is my solution:

```php
$url = [];
$dates = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : null;
if($dates){

  foreach($dates as $date){
     $url['date'][] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
  }

}

$query = http_build_query($url);
```

Then I can simply just redirect to `$query`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an integer $i

```
['date'.$i => date('Y-m-d'
```

You will have date1= &date2= & date3=

Answer (score 0):

You can add your date as array i.e. **date[]**.

Your URL would look like:

```
example.org/consols?date[]=2020-03-04&date[]=2020-03-05&date[]=2020-03-06
```

When you console your query it will give you

```
{ date: [ '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-06' ] }
```