# PHP - Implode, Explode works sometimes, and sometimes not?

Tags: php, explode, implode

I `SELECT` two things from my database and want to give them with GET to my view side. 
This is how my code looks:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT points, userstory FROM storypoints_summary WHERE session_id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $session_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $db_point, $db_userstory);

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
    array_push($points, $db_point);
    array_push($userstorys, $db_userstory);
}
mysqli_close($db);

$points = implode(",", $points);
$userstorys = implode(",", $userstorys);
```

After this i give them as i told with GET as followed:

```
header("location: story_overview_view.php?points=$points&userstorys=$userstorys");
die();
```

Now explode them in the View:

```
$points = explode(",", htmlspecialchars($_GET['points']));
$userstorys = explode(",", htmlspecialchars($_GET['userstorys']));

$count = count($points);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo $points[$i] . "<br>";
echo $userstorys[$i];
}
```

The problem now is, that points works, but *userstorys* doesn't. Both are *varchars* in the database. 
When I delete implode and explode from *userstorys*, then it prints *Array*. So thats its not an Array isn't the problem. 
If I delete implode and explode again and give with GET but only `...=$userstorys[0]`, it gives me the first and right value.

Comment: Could you print out `print_r($_GET['points])` and ``print_r($_GET[userstorys])` at top of ` `story_overview_view.php`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter this should help you.

Comment: no it doesn't lead me to my view page. And why someone clodes my question if the other doesn't help