# how to send query parameter which is a list which has strings (a string has comma)

Tags: query-string, encodeuricomponent

```
request

{
  params: {
    devices: ['iPad12,1', 'LH-12', 'LX-12']
  }
}
```

to send a `devices` query parameter with array, I reduced array to a string with comma. ('iPad12,1,LH-12,LX-12')

in this situation,
if a device name has a comma(like `iPad12,1`), backend recognize this query patemeter like ['iPad12', '1', 'LH-12', 'LX-12'].

Is there the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try encoding the params. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter

Comment: An idea would be to use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) - if multiple scenarios. Example: `qs.stringify(['iPad12,1', 'LH-12', 'LX-12'])` returns `"0=iPad12%2C1&1=LH-12&2=LX-12"`